# Proof verification: Possibly false argument in the proof of $\int_{I}g(x)dF(u)=\int_{I}g(u)F'(u)du$ (Riemann-Stieltjes)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

In [this](http://www.maths.lth.se/matstat/kurser/mas213/riemannstieltjes.pdf) paper, I am questioning the proof of the following lemma (Lemma 2, page 5):

> Assume $F$ is differentiable with $F'=f$ continuous. Then if $g$ is integrable,
>   $$\int_{I}g(x)dF(u)=\int_{I}g(u)F'(u)du.$$

Here is the proof they give:

> "We derive the result via Riemann-Stieltjes sums: In the sum
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})(F(x_{i})-F(x_{i-1}))$$
>   the factor $(F(x_{i})-F(x_{i-1}))=f(\eta_{i})(x_{i}x_{i-1})$ for some $\eta_{i}\in(x_{i-1},x_{i})$, by the Mean Value Theorem. Therefore
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})(F(x_{i})-F(x_{i-1}))=\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})f(\eta_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1}),$$
>   which we recognize as a Riemann sum for the integral $\int gfdu$ and the result is proven."

I dont think his final argument need to be true. Since I encountered a similar argument yesterday in another [paper](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~bruin/ET3.pdf) (page 25), I asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598941/approximating-the-riemann-integral-for-a-certain-product?noredirect=1#comment7398265_3598941) on Stack Exchange yesterday (notation differs a little). One of the comments convinced me even more that this argument may be false. The problem (in the proof that I copied above) is that the variable $\xi_{i}$ in $g$ and $\eta_{i}$ in $f$ may differ.

Can someone please explain his last argument? I.e. the Riemann integral estimation. I am so confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is a limiting argument using uniform continuity of $f$ which implies that if the width of partition is small enough $|f(\eta_i)-f(\xi_i)|$ is uniformly small, so one can replace $\eta_i$ with $\xi_i$ and get a "true Riemann" sum; the comment in the post referred is irrelevant since it applies to a fixed partition, while here partitions have small enough width; one can write a formal limit argument easily, but it is best to try to understand this by yourself as these types of shorthand arguments are common in literature and one goes nowhere until getting them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since one typically assumes that $g$ is bounded and $I = [a,b]$ is a compact interval, one can use that $f$ is uniform continuous on $I$. Let $\delta>0$ be chosen such that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies that $$|f(x)-f(y)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{\|g\|_\infty (b-a)}.$$
Now if the partition is chosen such that the mesh is less than $\delta$, then we get that the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})f(\eta_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$
differs from
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})f(\xi_i)(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$
only by an amount of
$$\Bigg| \sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})f(\eta_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}g(\xi_{i})f(\xi_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1}) \Bigg| \leq \|g\|_\infty (b-a) \max_i |f(\xi_i) - f(\eta_i)| < \varepsilon.$$
This argument completes the proof of the mentioned 'derivate-rule'.

Additional comment: If one likes Stieltjes-Lebesgue-Integrals, this formula says that the measure induced by $F$ is absolute continious with respect of the Lebesgue-measuren with Radon-Nikodym derivate given by $F'$.